# WordPress: Advanced Custom Fields - Field has "#" character, How To Call It To Display?

Tags: php, wordpress

As the title says, using Advanced Custom Fields we created a field named "Item #", but when using the function get_field("item #"), it doesn't work. I'm sure it's because of the pound sign.

Should I rename it or is there a way to make this work? Thanks in advance! (Btw, will renaming it to "Item Num" mess up all the associations it has with custom taxonomies and current data, or is that on an id basis?)

Here's the code:

```
  <?php if (is_page(19)) { $args = array("post_type" => "products", "posts_per_page" => "-1", "product category" => "Gas Turbine Hardfacing and Welding Wire"); } query_posts($args); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                        <tr>

                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="products-selected" value="<?php the_id(); ?>" /></td>

                            <td><?php echo get_field('item #'); ?></td>

                            <td><?php the_title(); ?></td>

                            <td></td>

                            <td></td>

                        </tr>               

                    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the `space` causes the issue. `Spaces` are not allowed in Field names in ACF. There were no problem with `item_#` in my test case.

---

Tested on:

- Advanced Custom Fields Version 3.5.3.1
- WordPress Version 3.4.2